# Recordings of WPF-LOB Training Sessions?

Tags: wpf

I was wondering if anyone recorded (audio or video) any of the WPF-LOB Training sessions put on by Karl Shifflett and Jaime Rodriguez? I was particularly interested in the databinding session. All of these sessions were so awesome (I attended the Chicago event) and wish that they had been recorded professionally.

thanks,
Bill

Comment: Have you asked Karl and Jaime?

Comment: You could inquire at Karl's blog http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/announcing-the-wpf-for-lob-training-tour/. He may know if Microsoft is going to provide it on events & webcasts at https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/AdvancedSearch.aspx?culture=en-US#advsearchloaded

Comment: Thanks - yes, I had spoken to both of them at the Chicago session and Jaime had said that they had day one recorded and Karl had said that he was planning on recording them but I don't know that it ever happened. Those were some awesome sessions. I thought maybe someone might have recorded some of them.